# Click event not firing (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this very simple code:

```
 $(function() {
     $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
     $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
 });

 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#submit").click(function() {
    var dataString = "datepicker="+$("#datepicker").val()+"&datepicker1="+$("#datepicker1").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?php echo $this->baseUrl()?>/index/getrange",
      data: dataString,
      success: function(response)
      {
          $("#table").html(response);
      }
    });
    return false;
   });
 });
```

The html is the following:

```
 <div id="welcome">
 <form action="javascript:void(0);" method="post" id="idForm">
 <p>Select a starting date:<br/>
 <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker"></p>
 <p>Select an ending date:<br/>
 <input type="text" id="datepicker1" name="datepicker1"></p>
 <input type="submit" value="Search for dates" id="submit">
 </form>
 </div>
 <div id="table"></div>
```

I cannot even debug it with firebug, cause it is just not firing the click event. Any idea?

Comment: Why not put the datepickers inside the $(document).ready function? Also, jsFiddle?

Comment: Seems to work here http://jsfiddle.net/xR6x8/

Comment: Then why is it not working in my browser? (I'm using firefox)

Comment: Just FYI: `$(function() {` and `$(document).ready(function(){` are the same thing.  No need to have both, just put all the code into one.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?  You are including jQuery, right?

Comment: try this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xR6x8/3/) and view your console. Does it show anything?

Comment: Yes not it has started to work... thanks you all

Comment: change the button type from "submit" to "button"

Comment: Not every user would click on the button... Consider [jQuery.submit()](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is working you probably have jquery ui not installed?

```
$(function() {
     $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
     $("#datepicker1").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
 });

 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#submit").click(function() {
    alert("clicked");
    var dataString = "datepicker="+$("#datepicker").val()+"&datepicker1="+$("#datepicker1").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?php echo $this->baseUrl()?>/index/getrange",
      data: dataString,
      success: function(response)
      {
          $("#table").html(response);
      }
    });
    return false;
   });
 });
```

check it out here.. http://jsfiddle.net/cxybg/1/